# StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer pool for synchronous methods

Tags: asp.net, .net, redis, connection-pooling, stackexchange.redis

Does implementing a ConnectionMultiplexer pool make sense if we use it for synchronous methods?

So by pool I mean creating multiple instances of StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer, storing those objects and when I want to communicate with Redis server I take the least used one from the pool. This is to prevent timeouts due to large queue size as per No. 10 suggestion in this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

I'm having doubts because I'm not sure how can a queue even happen if connectionMultiplexer blocks a thread until a call returns.

It seems to me that having a pool is pointless with sync method calls, but Redis best practice articles suggest creating this kind of pool regardless of method type (sync/async)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused here. `ConnectionMultiplexer` does not "get blocked". Creating a `ConnectionMultiplexer` gives you a factory-like object with which you can create `IDatabase` instances. You then use these instances to perform normal Redis queries. You can also do Redis queries with the connection multiplexer itself, but those are server queries and unlikely to be done often.
So, to make things short, it can help tremendously to have a pool of connection multiplexers, regardless of sync/async/mixed usage.

---

To expand further, here's a very simple pool implementation, which can certainly be enhanced further:

```
public interface IConnectionMultiplexerPool
{
    Task<IDatabase> GetDatabaseAsync();
}

public class ConnectionMultiplexerPool : IConnectionMultiplexerPool
{
    private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer[] _pool;
    private readonly ConfigurationOptions _redisConfigurationOptions;

    public ConnectionMultiplexerPool(int poolSize, string connectionString) : this(poolSize, ConfigurationOptions.Parse(connectionString))
    {
    }

    public ConnectionMultiplexerPool(int poolSize, ConfigurationOptions redisConfigurationOptions)
    {
        _pool = new ConnectionMultiplexer[poolSize];
        _redisConfigurationOptions = redisConfigurationOptions;
    }

    public async Task<IDatabase> GetDatabaseAsync()
    {
        var leastPendingTasks = long.MaxValue;
        IDatabase leastPendingDatabase = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < _pool.Length; i++)
        {
            var connection = _pool[i];

            if (connection == null)
            {
                _pool[i] = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(_redisConfigurationOptions);

                return _pool[i].GetDatabase();
            }

            var pending = connection.GetCounters().TotalOutstanding;

            if (pending < leastPendingTasks)
            {
                leastPendingTasks = pending;
                leastPendingDatabase = connection.GetDatabase();
            }
        }

        return leastPendingDatabase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO It is not recommended to use a pool of ConnectionMultiplexer,as regard to what this issue mentioned https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1279

Comment: Can you please include the most important information from the link here as a quote.

Comment: "- in general, if you have high volumes of small operations: multiplexed
connection sharing is hugely beneficial - reducing packet fragmentation etc
- however, if you have large payloads, it jams the pipe and a lot of small
ops can get nuked by a single large op“

Comment: the quote above tells that how a connectionMultiplexer benefits, that is by reducing packet fragmentation,and by saving client waiting time (which is mentioned here https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers). But in another use case ,using a pool of connectionMultiplexer led to timeout problems.As for this problem i only read a  bug fix report in a Chinese well-known blog site(https://www.cnblogs.com/cmt/p/16405164.html),which makes sense to me but i assume it's easy to find a report alike in English.